# In Java, how can I differentiate constructors with the same signiture?

Tags: java, constructor

I need to sort a linkedlist containing different colours by quantity of each colour. I figured I would store an integer of the amount of each colour in the linked list for when I get to overriding the comparator for sorting. As these will then need to be sorted again by date, already having a counted quantity of each colour prepared seemed like an easy first step.

The problem I'm having is adding these numbers as entries to my LinkedList, it's calling a constructor with an integer parameter because I'm adding single integer values. What can I do to accomplish what I'm trying without clobbering the value made by the current single parameter constructor? I tried using an enum but I don't think that would work in this scenario.

This is the constructor that's being called that I wish to avoid being used in this constructor.

```
public AttackVirus(int blockedVirusCount){
    this.blockedVirusCount = blockedVirusCount;
}
```

in my city class this is how I'm counting.

```
for (int i = 0; i < virusList.size(); i++) {
    String test = virusList.get(i).getType();
    if (test.equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {
        redVirus++; 

//This repeats for like 4 else if's for different colours.

AttackVirus numRed = new AttackVirus(redVirus);
//Repeat for numBlue, numYellow, ect
```

then I add it to my list using this following foreach

```
for (AttackVirus virus : Arrays.asList(numRed, numBlue, numYellow, numBlack, numGreen)) {
    this.virusList.add(virus);
}
```

I tried to use an enum I don't think I was using it correctly as the IDE told me that I'm trying to instantiate an enum.
I would like to see in my LinkedList:

```
type = "green"
time = "Mon Oct 25 15:48:00 EDT 2021"
blockedVirusCount = 1
blueVirus = 0
redVirus = 2
yellowVirus = 0
blackVirus = 3
greenVirus = 3


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class AttackVirus {
    public String type;
    public Date time;
    public int blockedVirusCount;
   public int blueVirus = 0, redVirus = 0, yellowVirus = 0, blackVirus = 0, greenVirus =0;

    public AttackVirus(String type, String time) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = null;
        try {
            this.type = type;
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            //formatter takes input in the form "yyyy-MM-dd HH;mm:ss"
            this.time = formatter.parse(time);
        } catch (Exception e1){
            System.out.println("AttackVirus Date Format Error!" + e1);
        }
    }
    public AttackVirus(int blockedVirusCount){
        this.blockedVirusCount = blockedVirusCount;
    }


//This doesn't work, because they share the same signiture as public AttackVirus(int blockedVirusCount)

    public void AttackVirus(int blueVirus){
        this.blueVirus =blueVirus;
    }
    public void AttackVirus(int redVirus){
        this.redVirus =redVirus;
    }
    public void AttackVirus(int yellowVirus){
        this.yellowVirus =yellowVirus;
    }
    public void AttackVirus(int blackVirus){
        this.blackVirus =blackVirus;
    }
    public void AttackVirus(int greenVirus){
        this.greenVirus =greenVirus;
    }
```

Comment: You can't have two constructors with the same signature. I'm not sure what you're asking because you don't show any constructor in your code and only one constructor call (`new AttackVirus(redVirus)`

Comment: Use [parameter objects](https://wiki.c2.com/?ParameterObject) or the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: What should your LinkedList contain: a sequence of `AttackVirus` instances (one for each color in red, green, blue, yellow, black)? Or should a single `AttackVirus` instance contain information about red, green, blue, yellow, black (and other fields like type and name)?

Comment: A sequence, because an attack can occur at different times, so each attack is it's own linkedlist index. But I only need a single index really to keep count of the total amount of viruses. This is in a graph so it look's convoluted but my debugger shows the following.

https://i.imgur.com/hQRzhUG.png

I will try updating my original post with more information.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to create an `AttackVirus` with only the red / green / blue / yellow / black count set is to create static factory methods:

```
public class AttackVirus {
    public String type;
    public Date time;
    public int blockedVirusCount;
    public int blueVirus = 0, redVirus = 0, yellowVirus = 0, blackVirus = 0, greenVirus =0;

    public AttackVirus(String type, String time) {
        try {
            this.type = type;
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            this.time = formatter.parse(time);
        } catch (Exception e1){
            System.out.println("AttackVirus Date Format Error!" + e1);
        }
    }

    public AttackVirus(int blockedVirusCount){
        this.blockedVirusCount = blockedVirusCount;
    }

    private AttackVirus() {
        // private constructor used by the factory methods below
    }

    public static AttackVirus redVirus(int redVirus) {
        AttackVirus result = new AttackVirus();
        result.redVirus = redVirus;
        return result;
    }

    public static AttackVirus blueVirus(int blueVirus) {
        AttackVirus result = new AttackVirus();
        result.blueVirus = blueVirus;
        return result;
    }

    // repeat for the other colors
}
```

But IMHO this design where one class has a lot of fields where only some of them are needed at any time is probably a bad design.